# Load image from .htaccess protected directory in React.native / HTMl

Tags: html, .htaccess, react-native

I have image files under .htaccess protected directory.
Whenever I tried to access the image on the browser, it asks me the username/pwd.

I am using simple  source to display that image file but obviously it doesn't.
How can I show the image file from protected directory?

Or what should i do in react native.
React native code:

```
<Image style={styles.logo} source={{uri: 'https://xxx.xxx.com/abc.jpg'}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do like that

```
<Image style={styles.logo} source={{uri: 'https://xxx.xxx.com/abc.jpg', headers: { Authorization: 'someAuthToken' }}}/>
```